# How could I select a row in QTableWidget?

Tags: qt, pyqt

I want to select a row in QTableWidget in my program. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Open Qt Assistant.
- Look for QTableWidget
- Find and click on 'List of all members, including inherited members', it is in the beginning.
- Ctrl + F
- enter 'selectrow'
- click on the found function and see what it does

Alternative way is to look directly for 'selectRow' in the Qt Assistant, but then you will have to know that QTableWidget inherits QTableView.

Hope this helps.